# how do I show a string as html content in web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to retrieve a html document to show in my web page, now the content comes from database as a string. Now I know there is a way to do this in win forms using Browser.DocumentText. But how do I do this in web form?

I tried the setting the innerHTML property for a div inside of the "OnRowCommand", the "OnRowCommand" happens to be inside an update panel. When I move the Div outside the panel, say to just below the body, it renders well.

Comment: Did you try assigning it to a `div` using `innerHTML` property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a literal control in aspx file and in codebehind set

`Literal1.Text=data_from_DB;`

Comment: This did not work for me but using passThrough did, e.g., passthrough for the win! `<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" ID="litError" runat="server" />` with `this.litError.Text = "Example link  <a href=\"https://www.google.com" target=\"_blank\">Google Search</a>";`

Answer (score 9):

Well there are many ways to do this, you can use a label, literal Controls.

Or maybe defining a public string within your page then use it directly in your html as:

```
<%= strSomeString %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`html` code:

```
 <div id="webcontent" runat="server">
 </div>
```

Code behind:

```
  webcontent.InnerHtml = FromDBstring;
```

Comment: I have tried this but this aint working...its assigning the innerHTml property as expected but nothing shows on screen :(

Comment: my bad...the position of the div was at a wrong place, somehow when the control which assigns the innerHTML happens to be inside an update panel, the rendering is not taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Write up for  Mvc app  `Html.Raw('html tages')` or `MvcHtmlString.Create('html tages')` and for web form `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode('html tages')`

Comment: you can simply use <%=yourstring%> instead. pay attention that it should be "=" instead.